# Trie Implementation in Python -- Print Keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, trie

I Implemented a Trie data structure using python, now the problem is it doesn't display the keys that Trie is stored in its data structure.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = [None] * 26
        self.endOfTheWord = False

class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = self.getNode()

    def getNode(self):
        return Node()

    def charToIndex(self ,ch):
        return ord(ch) - ord('a')             

    def insert(self ,word):
        current = self.root
        for i in range(len(word)):
            index = self.charToIndex(word[i])

            if current.children[index] is None:
                current.children[index] = self.getNode()

            current = current.children[index]

        current.endOfTheWord = True

    def printKeys(self):
        str = []
        self.printKeysUtil(self.root ,str)

    def printKeysUtil(self ,root ,str):

        if root.endOfTheWord == True:
            print(''.join(str))
            return

        for i in range(26):

            if root.children[i] is not None:
                ch = chr(97) + chr(i)
                str.append(ch)
                self.printKeysUtil(root.children[i] ,str)
                str.pop()
```

Comment: "it doesn't display the keys that Trie is stored in its data structure." - Probably, you observe unexpected behavior when perform some actions (call methods of your classes). Please, add to the question post: 1. What **exact** actions you have performed (if you call them in some other code, show that code). 2. What exact output you got. 3. Describe, why this output is not expected by you. Without detailed description of the problem the question is unclear and thus cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a pre-order traversal of the nodes, and wherever you find an end-of-word marker, you zoom up to the root, capturing the letters as you go, in order to get the full word... except that to accomplish this, you would need to store the parent node in each node.

Answer (score 0):

```
def printKeysUtil(self ,root ,str):

        if root.endOfTheWord == True:
            print(''.join(str))
            return

        for i in range(26):

            if root.children[i] is not None:
                ch = chr(97+i)
                str.append(ch)
                self.printKeysUtil(root.children[i] ,str)
                str.pop()
```